# Массив строк в бинарный вид

Tags: lua

Есть массив вида

```
local array = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x03, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C };
```

Требуется все символы перевести в бинарный вид. Есть ли в Lua стандартные функции если не то как тогда лучше это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

чтоб не сильно парится с вычислениями

```
function sixteenToTwo(sixteen) -- из 16 в 2
 local tow;
  if (sixteen=="0")then tow="00000000";
  elseif(sixteen=="1")then tow="00000001";
  elseif(sixteen=="2")then tow="00000010";
  elseif(sixteen=="3")then tow="00000011";
  elseif(sixteen=="4")then tow="00000100";
  elseif(sixteen=="5")then tow="00000101";
  elseif(sixteen=="6")then tow="00000110";
  elseif(sixteen=="7")then tow="00000111";
  elseif(sixteen=="8")then tow="00001000";
  elseif(sixteen=="9")then tow="00001001";
  elseif(sixteen=="A")then tow="00001010";
  elseif(sixteen=="B")then tow="00001011";
  elseif(sixteen=="C")then tow="00001100";
  elseif(sixteen=="D")then tow="00001101";
  elseif(sixteen=="E")then tow="00001110";
  elseif(sixteen=="F")then tow="00001111";
  end;
 return tow;
end;
```